# ES6 promises: how to chain functions with arguments

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

How to chain functions with delays. I tried the following:

```
Promise.resolve()
.then(setKeyframe('keyframe-0'))
.then(delay(3000))
.then(setKeyframe('keyframe-1'))
.then(delay(3000))
.then(setKeyframe('keyframe-2'))
;

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

function setKeyframe (name) {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName('animation-container')[0];
  element.className = 'animation-container ' + name;
}
```

All functions seem to be called immediately after each other. The delay function does not delay the chain. What am I missing?

Comment: You have to pass a callback that returns a promise into `then`, not a promise itself.

Comment: you're starting all of the actions at once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.then()` accepts a function, which may or may not return a promise

You are however passing a promise directly

```
// Yes
Promise.resolve().then(() => { return new Promise(); });

// No
Promise.resolve().then(new Promise());
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand your answer. Are you talking about the delay() function? What's the difference between 'passing a function that returning a promise' and 'passing a promise directly'?

Comment: @Sven, no, both of them. See my answer.

Comment: It is the difference between...
Promise.resolve().then(new Promise());
Promise.resolve().then(() => { return new Promise(); });

Comment: Correct solution could be shortened to `Promise.resolve().then(() => new Promise());`

Answer (score 5):

Your mistake might be easier to spot with a function without arguments:

The right way:

```
Promise.resolve().then(setFirstKeyframe)
```

Above, the function `setFirstKeyframe` is an argument to `.then`, for the promise to call later.

The wrong way:

```
Promise.resolve().then(setFirstKeyframe())
```

Here, `setFirstKeyframe` is called immediately (!), and its result (a promise) is passed to `then` (which gets ignored as `then` expects a function).

For functions with arguments use an anonymous function:

```
Promise.resolve().then(function() {
  return setFirstKeyframe('keyframe-0');
})
```

This is where [es6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) rock:

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => setFirstKeyframe('keyframe-0'))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you were calling all functions instead of providing them as handlers.

```js
Promise.resolve('keyframe-0')
.then(setKeyframe)
.then(delay(3000, 'keyframe-1'))
.then(setKeyframe)
.then(delay(3000, 'keyframe-2'))
.then(setKeyframe)
;

function delay(ms, value) {
  return function (val) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms, value !== undefined ? value : val);
    });
  };
}

function setKeyframe(name) {
  var element = document.body;
  element.className = 'animation-container ' + name;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.keyframe-0 { background: red; }
.keyframe-1 { background: green; }
.keyframe-2 { background: blue; }
```

Comment: Better rename it to `makeDelayer` or so, to make clear that it's not creating a delay right away.