# wrapping promise+then in new promise

Tags: es6-promise

I have a simple promise:

```
function p(l) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    alert(l);
    resolve();
  });
}
```

I then try to create a promise that will only resolve after it's then clause:

```
function pp(l1, l2) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    p(l1).then(() => {
      alert(l2);
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

I now do:

```
p('start').then(pp('A', 'B')).then(p('end'));
```

I expected to see: start, A, B, end
but instead I see: start, A, end, B

why ?

how can I achieve what I want, creating a promise (pp) that will resolve when it's then clause finished ?

Comment: `.then(() => pp('A', 'B'))` will fix your problem. Making detailed answer.

Comment: This will give you the sequence you want **p('start').then(p('A')).then(p('B')).then(p('End'));**, but if you have a promise that resolve **nothing** it make not sense. You can do the same with alert('start');alert('A');alert('B');alert('end');. It really make not sense to have a promise that resolve nothing.

Comment: coyotte508 - no, this gives me: start, end ,A, B

Comment: Hosar - no, I don't want to change the structure of the code, it's only a sample, I want to create a promise with a then cause that can then be chained as a single unit

Comment: added working demo

Comment: `p` and `pp` are functions, not promises. Your terminology here is confused. Promises do not "wrap" functionality, they're mere return values you attach callbacks to. `then()` [expects functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627845/es6-promises-how-to-chain-functions-with-delays/36657418#36657418) not promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pp` can be coded more simply:

```
function pp(l1, l2) {
  return p(l1).then(() => {
    alert(l2);
  });
}
```

This is the whole point of promises, if you have to write complicated code everytime, it's not worth it :)

Also, `.then` expects a function callback with in parameter the return value of the previous promise/function.

```
p('start').then(() => pp('A', 'B')).then(() => p('end'));
```

As for the precise reason you had your behavior, outside of not using the `.then` chaining as it's meant to be, I'm not very clear why.

And the reason this code works, is because when returning a `Promise` inside a callback, that `Promise` is executed, and the value it resolves to is passed to the next callback as an argument. `() => pp('A', 'B')` being equivalent to `() => { return pp('A', 'B');}`, `pp` is returned and waited upon before calling the next callback of the chain.

If you want to keep the same `.then` calling syntax, then changing `pp` to return a callback instead of a `Promise` would work:

```
function pp(l1, l2) {
  return () => p(l1).then(() => {
    alert(l2);
  });
}
```

But then you can no longer use it as a `Promise`. The last part of the chaining still needs to change: `.then(() => p('end'))`.

Comment: thx ! the problem with this is that it moves the responsibility to the top level to call pp in the right way(with () => pp('A', 'B') .. ) .. which is not what I'm looking for. I want the top code to chain it without knowing that it has a 'then' clause ...

you can change your answer to move the return ()=> ... inside pp, then I'll mark it

Comment: how about: function pp(l1, l2) {
  return () => { p(l1).then(() => {
    alert(l2);
  });
}} ? (added {} ) ... is this safe ? can I then still use it as a promise ?

Comment: @kofifus if you add `{}` you also need to add `return`: `function pp(l1, l2) {
  return () => { return p(l1).then(() => {
    alert(l2);
  });} ;
}`

Comment: why ? it works without the return ... also is that the same as your solution ? is it safer ?

Comment: @kofifus It works in this specific case, for this specific engine, but if your promise took longer, for example the return value of an ajax code, it wouldn't work. If you don't return the promise, the browser won't wait for it to end, won't pass its resolved value to the next callback, and whichever code is called next is **undetermined**. That it works for this specific case is your luck, but if instead of `alert` you'd use some non blocking code with an actual delay, it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

In your second function try following

```
function pp(l1, l2) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    alert(l1);
    alert(l2);
    resolve();
  });
}
```

Or if you want to put `p` function inside `pp` then

```
function pp(l1, l2) {
  return p(l1).then(() => {
    alert(l2);
  });
}



p('start').then(() => pp('A', 'B')).then(() => p('end'));
```

Here is Demo https://plnkr.co/edit/fUisfcWrTu89xcc4j0cu?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) - "onFulfilled: A **Function** called when the Promise is fulfilled. This function has one argument, the fulfillment value."

the problem with my code was that in `then(pp('A', 'B'))` I passed `then` a *value* (the result of pp() which is a promise) and not a *function* (a function that receives the fulfillment value of the calling promise)

So the correct way to use then is to always pass it a function:

```js
function p(l) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    alert(l);
    resolve();
  })
}


function pp(l1, l2) {
  return p(l1).then(() => p(l2));
}


p('start').then(() => pp('A', 'B')).then(() => p('end'));
```