# Promise.resolve inside then() method does not pass its resolved value

Tags: es6-promise

I found an interest thing about Promise. When I run the following codes, it gave me the output of 'aa' as oppose to 'bb', which confused me a lot. Does anyone understand why and give a explanation, please? Thanks!

```js
Promise.resolve('aa')
.then(Promise.resolve('bb'))
.then(console.log);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 promises: how to chain functions with arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627845/es6-promises-how-to-chain-functions-with-arguments)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, you're misusing a `.then()` handler so it is no surprise that you don't get the desired answer.

A `.then()` handler should be passed a function reference.  You are passing it a promise which it dutifully ignores because it's not a callable function.

When you do this:

```
.then(Promise.resolve('bb'))
```

That executes `Promise.resolve('bb')` immediately and passes the return result (which is a promise) to `.then()`.  So, you're passing a promise to `.then()` when you should be passing a function reference.  If you change your code to this, then you will get what you expect:

```js
Promise.resolve('aa')
    .then(function() {return Promise.resolve('bb');})
    .then(console.log);
```

Remember, the point of passing something to `.then()` is that it can be executed LATER when the parent promise resolves/rejects.  So, for that to be possible, you have to pass a function reference that can be called by the promise infrastructure at some later time.

Using ES6 syntax, you could shorten to this:

```
Promise.resolve('aa')
  .then(_ => Promise.resolve('bb))
  .then(console.log);
```

Comment: @Yizhe - Since it appears you may be new here.  If this answers your problem, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  T'his will also earn you a few reputation points here for following the proper procedure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, @jfriend00!