# How to chain different async operations wrapped in promises correctly

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, promise, xmlhttprequest

At the moment my understanding of promises is simply that of a wrapper for async functions native to the outer environment (the browser, node.js etc). I am confused as to how to actually write software that connects async operations together properly using promises. Here is my problem:

In the code below a `setTimeout` function is wrapped in a promise. I have also wrapped an `XMLHttpRequest` call in a promise. I assumed ( wrongly) that if I chain them together in the following manner that the timer would run and *then* the AJAX call would be made. This does not happen. The AJAX call happens first.

```
timer(1000).then(AJAXGetRequest('https://itunes.apple.com/hk/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json'))
```

If I change my promise chain to look like the following,  it work as expected!

```
timer(1000).then(function(){
    AJAXGetRequest('https://itunes.apple.com/hk/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json')
})
```

The problem with the preceding code is that I am reverting back to using callbacks for async operations.
I assume there is a way to write my code so I don't have to revert back to callbacks and that I can do something like this:

```
timer(1000)
    .then(AJAXGetRequest('some/api'))
    .then(timer)  // wait
    .then(AJAXGetRequest('someOther/api'))
    .then(timer)  // wait
    .then(AJAXGetRequest('another/api'))
                  // wait
```

Or even more flexible:

```
timer(1000)
    .then(AJAXGetRequest('some/api'))
    .then(timer(200))  // wait
    .then(AJAXGetRequest('someOther/api'))
    .then(timer(600))  // wait
    .then(AJAXGetRequest('another/api'))
                  // wait
```

Below is the rest of the code for the previous examples:

```
let timer = function(value) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        setTimeout(() => {

            console.log(value);
            resolve(value); 

        }, value);

    });
};


let AJAXGetRequest = function(URL) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var getRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        getRequest.open('get', URL, true);
        getRequest.send();

        getRequest.onload = function() {

            var JSONObject = JSON.parse(getRequest.responseText);
            console.log(JSONObject);
            resolve(JSONObject); // object
        }


    });
};
```

Comment: Promises never promised no callbacks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 promises: how to chain functions with arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627845/es6-promises-how-to-chain-functions-with-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

`<Promise>.then` takes a function, if you give it a promise it will not know what to do with it.

You can solve that by changing what you pass in to `.then` to match that signature:

```js
timer(1000)
.then(() => AjaxRequest(url1))
.then(() => timer(1000))
.then(() => AjaxRequest(url2))
.then(() => timer(1000));
```